# linq to xml with C# and VS2008

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

XML Formatted

```
<status>
 <webresponse>
  <properties>
   <props>
    <imghandle>
     <image handle=1234>
      <imagetag>somewhere</imagetag>
     </image>
    </imghandle>
   </props>
   <props>
    <imghandle>
     <image handle=1235>
      <imagetag>somewhere1</imagetag>
     </image>
    </imghandle>
   </props>
  </properties>
 </webresponse>
</status>
```

The above is sample of the xml returned to me by a thrid party. I am trying to use Linq to XMl to build my object and I am trying to navigate to `<imghandle>/<image handle=1234>`. I can do it with Xpath but when i do the following, I get object ref not set error

```
from c in searchXMLResult.Descendants("props")
select c.Element("imghandle").Element("image").Attribute("handle");
```

PS: I know my xml is not formatted well for readability, how does one place XML sections when asking a question here?

Update 1:
So after much irritating the 3rd party, I finally get an answer saying that the data i was consuming was outdated and they gave me the new formatted data which lookis like this

```
<status>
     <webresponse>
      <properties>
       <props>
        <imghandle>
         <image handle="1234">
          <imagetag>somewhere</imagetag>
         </image>
        </imghandle>
        <owner>
          <image handle="ABcf">
          </image>
        </owner>
       </props>
       </properties>
     </webresponse>
    </status>
```

I tried Kevin Thige's suggestion, look at the user suggestions below, and i get an object ref error. Can not having the same element under 2 different sections not work with Linq to XML? i.e

```
from c in searchXMLResult.Descendants("props")
```

select c.Element("imghandle").Element("image").Attribute("handle");

and/or

```
from c in searchXMLResult.Descendants("props")
```

select c.Element("owner").Element("image").Attribute("handle")

Update2:
This is the xml that I am getting and saved to disk

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<status>
  <webresponse>
    <properties>
      <props>
        <imghandle>
          <image handle="537">
            <imagetag>SFO</imagetag>
          </image>
        </imghandle>
        <owner>
          <image handle="User-2">
            <firstname>
            </firstname>
            <lastname>Site Administrator</lastname>
            <username>admin</username>
          </image>
        </owner>
        <creationdate>2009-03-06T18:07:57Z</creationdate>
        <summary>
        </summary>
      </props>
      <status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</status>
    </properties>
  </webresponse>
</status>
```

Comment: I went ahead and formatted the XML.  The best way to do this is to select the range you want formatted and hit CTRL+K

Answer (score 2):

The code below works for me, once I put quotes around the 'handle' attribute values:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"
<status>
 <webresponse>
  <properties>
   <props>
    <imghandle>
     <image handle='1234'>
      <imagetag>somewhere</imagetag>
     </image>
    </imghandle>
   </props>
   <props>
    <imghandle>
     <image handle='1235'>
      <imagetag>somewhere1</imagetag>
     </image>
    </imghandle>
   </props>
  </properties>
 </webresponse>
</status>
");

var v = from c in xdoc.Descendants("props")
select c.Element("imghandle").Element("image").Attribute("handle");
```

EDIT:  Without modifying the input to make the xml valid, I don't know what you can do with the XDocument or XmlDocument objects.  Both will throw exceptions if you try to load the invalid xml.

EDIT2:  The 2nd xml example is still not valid :(.  The tag `<image handle='ABcf'>` is not closed.

Comment: That's great, but the OP doesn't seem to have control over the input. Is there a way to do it without modifying the input?

Comment: does the attribute value need to be enclosed with single quotes or would double quotes be suffice. also i do not have conntrol over the data coming to me

Comment: @Whatsit - good point.  Hmm, without the quotes (single or double) it's not valid xml.  I'm not sure what the options are for dealing with invalid xml using XDocument.

Comment: Kevin: I followed your sample and did this
 XDocument searchXMLResult = XDocument.Parse(searchResult.OuterXml.ToString().Trim());

var v = from c in xdoc.Descendants("props")
select c.Element("imghandle").Element("image");

where searchresult is of type XMLDocument. Still gave me an error. I did put double quotes around the attribute values, getting the third party to get me the right xml is like going to the DMV

Comment: What error are you getting? Does the XDocument.Parse() line fail or is it the Linq statement?

Comment: In the Linq statement, when i expand on the results, I get object ref not set error. also I updated my question and the xml data I am now getting back

Comment: The same linq statement worked ok for me with the new xml sample, once I fixed the image tag that wasn't closed.  I think the xml you're working with might not be exactly the same as what you posted above.  Could you post the raw xml that gets loaded into searchXMLResult?